# LoadTest in Windows Based application

Tags: ajax, vb.net, wcf, web-services

I would like to do load testing in windows based application for a webservice. I will be calling a WCF Service from Windows Application which in turn calls the webservice to retrieve the results. It will accept input xml and outputs response xml.

How can I do load testing by using for loops in an asynchronous way. I don't want to use any load testing tools.

The Client reports that the "Record does not exist" is coming sometimes. But for me it is working fine. I would like to reproduce the result.

Currently I am sequentially writing the response xml to a text file. I would like to need this as asynchronous.

**UPDATE:** 
I want to switch over from windows based application to web based application to do load test with Ajax. I would like to know how to write the Ajax code for input xml and get response xml in the form of text files

Comment: Why would you want to load test without custom tools? There are many many things you'll find difficult to implement manually (testing different network qualities, goal based loading, monitoring the server process, etc...). A simple `for` loop is never going to do what you want - not least because it's single-threaded - you'll need to maintain multiple connections simultaneously, otherwise, it's not a load test

Comment: What is the best, free and simple tool to do load testing to send input xml and get response xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your WCF service supports multiple threads.
2. Generate proxy with asynchronous methods.
3. Spawn a lot of Begin[YourMethodName] function calls on your proxy object.

Comment: Is there any sample code for this. I could not get it completely

Comment: Please see my update in the Question. I would like to do with Ajax.